# Place x axis labels on the inside of rotated graph ggplot2 r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have created a plot in ggplot2 and was wondering if there is any way in which to get the x axis LABELS to be placed on the inside of the plot as it would tidy it up a lot and I can't work out where this command would be.  Code and plot below, any help greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
ggplot(gen, aes(Genera, y = Depth.occurred)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(x = "Genera", y = "Depth (m)") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0, 90, by = 10)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 12)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=30, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  stat_n_text(size = 3, y.pos = 1, fontface = "italic") +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, vjust = 1))
```

plot created here:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIXtt.jpg)

updated plot using the first method below (y position edited) but strange font on some labels [updated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHms3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to set axis labels inside within regular ggplot expression as I don't see the option on themes, but you can just suppress x axis text labels, and add the x axis labels as geom_text within the plot

```
# what you have so far minus theme(axis.text.x), and combining theme elements

gg <- ggplot(gen, aes(Genera, y = Depth.occurred)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=30, linetype="dashed", color = "red") +
  stat_n_text(size = 3, y.pos = 1, fontface = "italic") +
  labs(x = "Genera", y = "Depth (m)") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(0, 90, by = 10)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size = 12), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size = 12),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(x=Genera, y=2, label=Genera))
```

Or you can obtain your plot ylims and set the geom_text y value to y max with some nudge factor since it looks like you have your n's also printed at y.pos=1

```
# y-range
gg_yrange <- ggplot_build(gg)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]]$y.range

gg + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(x=Genera, y=p_yrange[1]-2, label=Genera))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first one worked really well (I just adjusted the positions of the n's and the text).  Do you happen to know why the font looks a bit strange for some of the geom_text labels?

Comment: Can you upload the new plot, I am not sure what instances you are referring to.  I only tried this on mtcars and might be specific to the length of your text labels(?).

Comment: edited, plot in description, thanks again for the help.  When labels are made bold it isn't as apparent, but just seems a little strange

Comment: ah I see what you mean, but I don't really have an idea of what's causing it. is it a rendering issue to image file?  if you plot it to window and resize your window up and down and still see it? if you change geom_text size, is it always the same labels that are weird? perhaps making labels bold is a good compromise